# Executing Python script on dropdown change in Django?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a simple Python script, `simple_script.py` that simply prints a string with the current datetime:

```
import datetime
print(f"Current time is: {datetime.datetime.now()}")
```

The script file is placed in a folder called `scripts` in the django projet's main folder.

On the site, I merely have a dropdown field (`<select>`) and a button. I want to have this script run every time the user changes the dropdown field, i.e. without the need to press the button (the button won't even be necessary - it's only here for demonstration purposes). I managed to implement the version where running the script depends on pressing the button.

My home.html:

```
<form action="/external/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select>
        <option>---</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select><br><br>
    {{data1}}<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Execute Custom Py Script">
</form>
```

My views.py:

```
import sys
from django.shortcuts import render
from subprocess import run, PIPE

def external(request):
    out = run([sys.executable, "scripts/simple_script.py"], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    return render(request, 'appName/home.html', {'data1': out.stdout.decode('utf-8')})
```

And I added the following path declaration to my `url.py`:

```
path('external/', views.external, name='external'),
```

Right now, upon pressing the button, the `{{data1}}` tag gets filled up with the string returned from `simple_script.py`. To get to my goal, I realize I likely need JavaScript, so I added an `onChange` attribute to the `<select>` tag like so: `<select onChange="runSimpleScript()">`.

My doubt is, how can I create the same kind of binding between my HTML file and views.py, that Django so conveniently provides using the Django template language? How can I run the script using JavaScript, and return the output of the script to the HTML template?

Answer (score 0):

you have to re-render the piece of html that you want to change with django information, something like this:

#### home.html

```
<form action="/external/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <select onchange=runSimpleScript()>
    <option>---</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <div id="data-from-script">
    {{data1}}
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Execute Custom Py Script">
</form>
<script>
  function runSimpleScript() {
    let xhttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("data-from-script").innerHTML = this.response
      }
    }
    xhttpRequest.open("GET", "./external/load-data/", true)
    xhttpRequest.send()
  }
</script>
```

So you have to create a separeted view to render only the part of the template that you want, in this case the div "data-from-script"

#### views.py

```
import sys
from django.shortcuts import render
from subprocess import run, PIPE

def external(request):
    out = run([sys.executable, "scripts/simple_script.py"], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    return render(request, 'appName/script.html', {'data1': out.stdout.decode('utf-8')})

def external_load_data(request):
    out = run([sys.executable, "scripts/simple_script.py"], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
    return render(request, 'appName/script-load-data.html', {'data1': out.stdout.decode('utf-8')})
```

Then add the path in your urls

#### urls.py

```
path('external/', views.external, name='external'),
path('external/load-data/', views.external_load_data, name='external_load_data'),
```

And finally create the html template

#### script-load-data.html

```
{{data1}}
```

I think this is it.